# Desktop App Converter

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have been using Desktop Bridge for some time and recently I have started experiencing a problem. It stopped building the packages. I have tried to install it on different Virtual Machines but I have been getting the same error.

```
PowerShell Error Record:
DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated environment. See inner exception for more details.
PowerShell Stack Trace:
at RaiseUserException, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\DACLogger.ps1: line 154
at Invoke-IsolatedInstall, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\IsolatedEnvironmentOps.ps1: line 162
at <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1: line 684
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1

Inner Exception[0]:
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_STARTING_ISOLATED_ENV_FAILED': Failed to start the isolated environment. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
Inner Exception Stack Trace[0]
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Inner Exception[1]:
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred." ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
Inner Exception Stack Trace[1]
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

Inner Exception[2]:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()<---

Inner Exception Stack Trace[2]
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.Start()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

Inner Exception[3]:
Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsException: HCS function call returned error. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
Inner Exception Stack Trace[3]
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.ProcessHcsCall(Int32 resultCode, String result)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.HcsFactory.Hcs.Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.IHcs.StartComputeSystem(IntPtr computeSystem, String options)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.Container.<StartAsync>d__8.MoveNext()

Inner Exception[4]:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070102): The wait operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070102)
[2017-07-25T11:07:56] The full error record is saved in the logs at C:\temp­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest servicing update for the Windows 10 Creators Update (KB4025342, build 15063.483) unfortunately introduced a bug in the OS that breaks the Desktop App Converter. We are working to get a fix out asap to address the regression. So until this bug is fixed you can only run the Desktop App Converter on systems that don’t have that particular servicing update KB4025342 applied.

**UPDATE**

A new baseimage for build 15063 has been posted here now. Please use BaseImage-15063-UPDATE.wim on machines that have the KB4025342 servicing update applied:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55325

Also see this blog post regarding this issue:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/08/04/desktop-app-converter-fails-on-windows-10-15063-483-and-later-how-to-solve-it/

Comment: Thank you, Stefan.

Comment: If you don't mind, please mark as answered so we get the question off the unanswered radar. Thx!

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT

Hi! Any news about the fix for 15063 or BaseImage-16251.wim availability? Thanks.

Comment: The 16251 image for insiders should get published today. The fix for 15063 is still in the works.

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT

Thank you.

Comment: 16251 is available now: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55325

Comment: I was able to uninstall KB4025342 and DAC resumed working on 15063.

Comment: BaseImage-15063-UPDATE.wim is now available. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: My -Cleanup appears to be stuck.. CPU is pinned but no disk activity after starting it a half hour ago. Safe to kill?