# Desktop Bridge app Issue access denied

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am trying to research the problem that I am facing right now. I created a desktop bridge app and it has access to Program files. When I run it on Windows 10 where Updates for Windows 19 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4025376) are installed everything is okay, but if I uninstall the updates and run my app I get access denied to Program files. What can be in an issue.I am trying to research but cannot find anything. Thanks

Comment: [KB4025376](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4025376) is Security Update for Adobe Flash Player. I don't think it will impact your desktop bridge app. Anyway, why you want to uninstall the **Security Update**? You should never do this.

Comment: because Desktop bridge converter app is not working with this updates

Comment: See this question for details and how to resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305456/desktop-app-converter

Answer (score 0):

The latest servicing update for the Windows 10 Creators Update (KB4025342, build 15063.483) unfortunately introduced a bug in the OS that breaks the Desktop App Converter.

A new baseimage for build 15063 has been posted now. Please use BaseImage-15063-UPDATE.wim on machines that have the KB4025342 servicing update applied: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55325

Also see this blog post regarding this issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/08/04/desktop-app-converter-fails-on-windows-10-15063-483-and-later-how-to-solve-it/

Comment: Hi Stefan, my question is not about Desktop Bridge converter, but about the app behavior. When Updates for Windows 19 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4025376) are installed, everything is fine; the app is running as usual and it has access to program files, but when I uninstall the updates i get the message error access denied to program files I tried it on several machines and it is always the same.

Comment: I uninstalled it to run the desktop bridge converter, and then I created the app I noticed that the app had no access to Program files, then I've started testing on different machines there updates were installed and everything was fine and the app had access to program files. I am testing the app and  I want to make sure that it runs all the time and does not have any issues.

Comment: Does this happen also on machines that never had the servicing update installed? Or only machines that had it applied and then removed?

Comment: No I don't have this issue on the machines where the servicing updates had never been installed.